# Handling unicode conversion in python

Tags: python, unicode

For my project, everything must be in unicode. Here is my way of handling everything, all strings are passed into this function:

```
def unicodify(string):
    if not isinstance(string, unicode):
        return string.decode('utf8', errors='ignore')
    return string
```

Is the following method good practice for production code? If not, why and how would you suggest decoding to unicode? The errors='ignore' actually does not work for ValueErrors 'invalid \x escape', but i'm not sure how to properly handle that.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Python do you use, 2 or 3?

Comment: @Tichodroma: 2, by the looks of it; Python 3 strings do not have a `.decode()` method.

Comment: The exception you see means that the input string is *not* UTF8 encoded.

Comment: Well thanks so far you guys but it's still not clear to me what to do. All my strings final output destination should be in unicode. Should I: Catch the ValueErrors and modify/skip the strings entirely? Or go into the strings and remove the \x value errors manually? Try to decode into some other encoding? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may have invalid string literal.

`\x` should be followed by two hex values(digits, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`).

Valid example:

```
>>> '\xA9'
'\xa9'
>>> '\x00'
'\x00'
>>> '\xfF'
'\xff'
```

Invalid example:

```
>>> '\xOO'
ValueError: invalid \x escape
>>> '\xl3'
ValueError: invalid \x escape
>>> '\x5'
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

See [**String literals**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Answer (score 0):

For you to even attempt to convert str type to unicode type you need to know the encoding of the data in str. utf8 is common, but not the only encoding out there.

Additionally, you could get str data that is not in any encoding (like arbitrary binary data). In that case you can not convert it to unicode. Or rather, you have two options: a) raise an exception or b) convert as much as you can and ignore errors. It depends on the application what you should do.